# Display content from Database (While loop) in C# / .NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, label, while-loop

I'm very new to .NET and unfortunately having to take over an ex-colleague's project.

Part of my code has a while loop to loop out query results...

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            pageTitle.Text = reader["title"].ToString();
        }
```

I am currently using this to retrieve the Page Title from a Table in my Database.

I want to display this in my `<title></title>` of the SiteMaster file, but unfortunately right now using this method:

`<title><asp:Label ID="pageTitle" runat="server" /></title>` is giving me a span tag inside the `<title>`. I want to remove the  altogether and just have the Title value.

Can anyone explain the best way to do this?

Appreciate your help and patience with this.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't that loop overwrite the previous titles if you have a result set of more than one item?  Is this the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `<head>` tag has the `runat="server"` attribute, for example:

```
<head runat="server">
```

Then set the title by using:

```
Page.Title = reader["title"].ToString();
```

Comment: Here is a link about how to do this:  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051006-1.aspx

Comment: Wow! Many Thanks, Dana!!! And if I were to do this for my meta keywords or meta description, would it be Page.Keywords =.... ?

Comment: @user644978: `Page.MetaKeywords` use VS intellisense once in a while. won't hurt :)

Comment: For .NET 4.0 you can use the `Page.MetaKeywords`. For previous versions you need to declare the tag `<meta id="Keywords" name="Keywords" />`, which will create an instance of `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta` that you can access from code.

Comment: Wow! Tremendous help again, Dana. Page.MetaKeywords and Page.MetaDescription worked mucho coolness. Thanks to @naveen too and @BiggsTRC for the linkage. You guys rock.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`<asp:Literal>` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) instead.

Comment: This would be my recommendation. asp:Label renders as span. Literal gives you what you need.

Comment: hmmm... why shouldn't he use `Page.Title`

Comment: He could, as dana has suggested. This is an answer to getting rid of the span tag as asked.

Comment: Thanks, Druid. I'll look into this tag just now and report back.

Comment: @Khepri and @Druid: I totally disagree. framework should be your friend right? whats the point in putting a literal inside the title tag and then calling the literal when you could just use `Page.Title`

Comment: @naveen: That's a question you could ask the OP :)